# Restrict multiple clicks on radio button

Tags: java, javascript

I have 2 radio buttons and on the `onClick()` event of these buttons a preview pane is shown that displays certain records, the count of number of records changes. I want to stop the consecutive increase or decrease of numbers if I click the same radio button continuously.

I am using Java and Javascript.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: how much minimum span should there be between consecutive clicks...?

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the radio button after one click using onlcick. for example,

```
<input type="radio" name="r" id="r" onclick="javascript:this.form.r.disabled=1;this.form.submit(); ">
```

Answer (score 0):

Somehow you will have to do it in server side also because if you reload the page things will be reset.

On client side you can do this using jQuery One() function . See [this](http://api.jquery.com/one/)

I have not tried in javascript